# Replicating execve in c (Linux)?

Tags: c, linux, exec

I am doing a project to learn how a program is executed in Linux. Basically, I am trying to replicate the functionality of execve by running a series of system calls in a c program to take an executable binary, load it into memory, and successfully run it.

Are there any relatively easy-to-understand online resources (or tips) I can use to learn how to do this? I don't have much experience with this, and I'm trying to learn. It seems like a fairly complicated task, and I'm completely stuck at the moment.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure it is even possible in its full generality. Why do you ask? Why can't you use `execve` (or study its implementation *inside* the kernel source code)? At least, perhaps focus first on replicating the `execve` of some simple statically linked executable (e.g. `sash`)

Comment: Why not look at the source code for [`execve`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/execve.c;h=5ee5ecbe55e69190ecba0e60bccdbc22f62c0244;hb=HEAD)?

Comment: A simple, statically-linked executable is fine. In fact, that's my starting point. I am just scavenging for some information now since I have no idea where to begin. The idea is that I need to set up the program's memory, load the program into it, and pass control over to it and let it go from there.

Comment: The tricky part is that if you want to do all that in user land, you'll do it inside some process which already has some address space, etc.... I'm not sure it is worth the effort... You might spend months on it (for little gain)... Read also the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf). Did you consider instead developing a new `execve`-like syscall? That is much more interesting!

Comment: Your main problem here is that part of the `exec` system call is overriding the process descriptor in the kernel. It's something you can't do in userspace. Even if you close all file descriptors there are still plenty of other values you can't reach. The basic approach to loading and running a code file would be to `mmap` it into the memory, then clear the stack, parse the ELP headers and jump to the program start function (assembly `jmp` instruction, mind you) But there's much more to an ELF file so it might not work without other initializations and dynamic linkage...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem here is that part of the `exec` system call is overriding the process descriptor in the kernel. It's something you can't do in userspace. 
Even if you close all file descriptors there are still plenty of other values you can't reach, nor can you free up dynamically loaded libraries and release you own program's code pages (since they would be write protected).

The basic approach to loading and running a code file would be to `mmap` it into the memory, then clear the stack, parse the ELF headers and jump to the program start function (assembly `jmp` instruction, mind you) But there's much more to an ELF file so it might not work without other initializations and dynamic linkage...

Comment: Thanks, I think that's pretty much exactly what I need to do. Now I just have to figure out how exactly to do what you said! :)